# Customized Comment Rendering - Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, comments

**In Visual Studio (2015) is it possible to change the color/font of lines within comments as viewed in the Text Editor using a custom token or indicator?** IE a manner that is similar to that of how Task List items can be assigned and are recognized by user-custom tokenization.

For example:

```
/*  --- Explanatory Comment ---

<>  This token is recognized, and the rest of this line appears in orange color.

<1> As a result of the token, this line now appears in a different font.
        + Additional information about the above; the text is light grey.

<?> This line appears in bold (and indicatively curious) blue text.

<!> Extra points, pending the possibility of the aforementioned that the
    remainder of the text in line with first character of this paragraph 
    also conforms to the style as defined by the token preceding it.

*/
```

- MSDN documentation seems to indicate that the creation of "*Custom
     Categories and Display Items*" can be achieved (With the addition of
     a VSPackage?) such that they would appear within the display options
     box of the fonts and colors under environment in the IDE's options
     menu (Options>Environment>Fonts and Colors).
- Or by some way of the "*IVsFontAndColorDefaultsProvider Interface*".

**Is there some known and/or preexisting manner in which to accomplish the previously described rendering or a preferable alternative (similar) solution?** If the above is the solution, any insight as to its implementation would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

***Note:** My intent is visual enhancement within my own VS Text Editor (potentially others with a package) for the purpose of clarity in such a case that hierarchical organization in comments would be beneficial; rendering to supplement ASCII characters alone.

MSDN Docs:

[Implementing Custom Categories and Display Items](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166178.aspx)

[IVsFontAndColorDefaultsProvider Interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivsfontandcolordefaultsprovider.aspx)